# Google Maps API v2 does not work with release key

Tags: android, google-maps

I've tried for about a week to solve this problem. I have google maps working perfectly fine in debug, but no matter what I do when I package the apk I get this error below

```
05-21 21:00:21.338  31534-31613/? E/Google Maps Android API﹕ Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

I've run the following command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/Documents/keys/phillybikeshare.jks -alias "pbs"
```

on two different keystores, took the SHA1 fingerprint that looks like

```
F9:DB:33:A2:05:02:80:5A:21:9A:19:E6:8A:E4:C4:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

and made api keys for the SHA1 in the google developer console. I even double checked to make sure I have a variable in both `main/res/values/google_maps_api.xml` and `debug/res/values/google_maps_api.xml` yet still nothing.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.peterchappy.phillybikeshare" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<permission
    android:name="com.peterchappy.phillybikeshare.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.peterchappy.phillybikeshare.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" >
</uses-feature>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".services.AlarmService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
</application>
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.peterchappy.phillybikeshare"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
}
```

I have no idea what could be wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you've enabled Google Maps for your release API Key?

Comment: I'm as positive as I can be. I have two SHA1 keys registered.

Comment: Another thing to check is that the package name for the app in the developer console matches the package name of your app.

Comment: copy and pasted my package name just in case, but not the issue...

Comment: Made my way though the list no luck :(

Comment: Sorry. I went to bed shortly after my response as it was late on the East Coast

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue before with my debug and release versions of my app.
I created two entries in Google's developer console.
One for the debug version using the SHA1 value from the debug.keystore
that you can find from your home directory in Windows.
e.g.

```
   C:\Users\<UserName\.android\debug.keystore.
```

And the other one, release version, is the SHA1 value from the .jks file that you used when you build the signed APK.

They need to match or else you will keep on getting that error.

And lastly, don't forget to clear data and cache when you uninstall the application as that could cause issue sometimes.

Comment: by "They need to match or else you will keep on getting that error."
do you mean the file/variable names because I'm doing that.
How do I clear the data and cache?

Comment: The API key that you are using with your manifest and the SHA1 value.
Go to Settings->Apps-><youapp> you will find there the buttons to delete the cache.

Comment: Unfortunately the clearing the cache did not work. And I do already have 2 entries in the google developer console. One for Debug and one for Release. Debug uses the debug.keystore SHA1 and Release uses my keystore with their corresponding API keys in `google_maps_api.xml`. Still no luck unfortunately no luck

Comment: I remember now. I also used the google_maps_api.xml as well but it didn't work . So, I just hard coded the value in the AndroidManifest.xml and that worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me thanks! How did you deal with debug versions them? Just swap them out?

Comment: yes, I just have to copy and paste it everytime. I put the two keys inside the manifest file but commented out so that I can easily copy paste it when I build different versions.