# Android app Google Maps API key does not work in published app

Tags: android, google-maps

I developed an app using Google Maps and was happy with the result until I gave it to the person under whose account it will actually be published (in beta test mode, actually). A new API key was generated with his account and the key updated in the app code, and now the map does not show, only a blank grey screen. We even regenerated the API key, deleted the API key on my account but still no go. We are also making use of the SHA-1 certificate fingerprint to restrict usage and verified from the actual APK that the SHA1 matches the one on developer console. So what could be causing this mess?

Answer (score 0):

I had to hardcode the API key in the manifest file. It was not enough to have a reference to it pointing to the value only specified in the google_maps_api.xml. Thanks to those who had the same problem! :)
Source:
[Google Maps API v2 does not work with release key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30387108/google-maps-api-v2-does-not-work-with-release-key?rq=1)